# List that contains some dataframes with NaN values. How to remove them?

Tags: r, dataframe, na

I want to make a single dataframe out of a list dataframes that contains a single row. I tried to binding them together to remove the NaN values but you can only bind if there is no NaN values!

What I got:

```
[[1]]
[1]          NaN 9.840158e+17

[[2]]
[1]          NaN 9.838244e+17

[[3]]
[1] 6.842105e-01 9.837743e+17

[[4]]
[1] 2.527174e+00 9.837643e+17

[[5]]
[1] 1.168269e+00 9.836988e+17

[[6]]
[1]         NaN 9.83663e+17
```

What I want:

```
[1]
      impact           id
6.842105e-01 9.837743e+17
2.527174e+00 9.837643e+17
1.168269e+00 9.836988e+17
```

What I tried:

```
bind_rows(data, .id = "id")

Error: Argument 1 must have names
```

for reproduction of the problem:

```
list(c(NaN, 984015782521835008), c(NaN, 983824424532144000), 
c(0.684210526315789, 983774270886236032), c(2.52717391304348, 
983764328443796992), c(1.16826923076923, 983698762760704000
), c(NaN, 983662953894435968))
```

Any tips on how to solve this?

Comment: The error relates to the list not having names, not the NaN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We remove the `list` element having `NaN` and then `rbind` the elements

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lst1[!sapply(lst1, function(x) any(is.nan(x)))])
colnames(out) <- c("impact", "id")
out
#       impact           id
#[1,] 0.6842105 9.837743e+17
#[2,] 2.5271739 9.837643e+17
#[3,] 1.1682692 9.836988e+17
```

---

Or another option is to `rbind` the elements and then use `na.omit`

```
na.omit(do.call(rbind, lst1))
```

---

Or with `Filter`

```
do.call(rbind, Filter(function(x) !any(is.nan(x)), lst1))
```

---

Or using `discard` (from `purrr`)

```
library(purrr)
discard(lst1, ~ any(is.nan(.x))) %>%
        do.call(rbind, .)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to remove NA's from dataframe you can use functions

## data

```
DF <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(0, 10, NA))

na.omit(DF)

print (DF)
x  y
1  0
2 10

na.exclude(DF)

print(DF)
x  y
1  0
2 10
```